# Matching using the new Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Does anyone have an example of doing matching using the new [Machine Learning functionality](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/machine-learning/) in Microsoft Azure?

The examples of doing classification make sense, and I was wondering if there was an example of doing matching using the built in tools. This would be instead of using classification and comparing those with my own custom codes. Either way an example would be nice.

I want to match two different entities based on location, demographic data, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, matching is very specific to industry. In general sense, you can use [hierarchal clustering in R](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/hclust.html), Featurize the entities using entity-properties and [cluster based on Euclidean distance](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html). This is not natively available in Azure ML but you can use create R and execute R modules in azure ML to integrate with R-scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I used the SQL Adapter then with a SQL query I was able to group and to calculate the averages. Nevertheless, you can use R as well.